# cfhttp issues as it is very slow, trying alternative

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am having issues with `cfhttp` as it is very slow, the Issue is I am making a call to the site to login and then get the cookie and make another call to the same url to get the DATA.

Here is my Code, I am lost a little bit if i try with `cfthread` how will i do that, any sample will be great

anotehr example is: I am trying a code

```
http://blog.1smartsolution.com/index.cfm/action:posts.entry/id:267/CFHTTP-Frustration.html
```

but this does not seems to retain the cookies, i tried every way i could, but it is not happening as my java knowledge is not vast,

please guide me, here is the code which i am trying:

```
<cfset cURL ="http://www.example.com/username=abc&password=xyz">

<cfhttp url="#cURL#" resolveurl="true" method="get">
        <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
        <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
    </cfhttp>
    <cfset st_cookies = cfhttp.responseHeader['Set-Cookie'] />
    <cfset st_temp = REReplace(st_cookies, ";.*", "")>
    <cfset st_cookieName = listfirst(st_temp,'=')>
    <cfset st_cookievalue = listlast(st_temp,'=')>
    <cfset cURL = cURL>
    <cfhttp url="#cURL#" method="get" throwOnError="Yes" resolveurl="true" result="objget">
        <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="#st_cookieName#" value="#st_cookievalue#">
    </cfhttp>
```

also when i use the the blog link way of doing the same thing, it says to me `Object Moved` .

what happens is, it just login and then it moves to another page

Comment: You can use 'cfx_http5' paid custom tag for HTTP requests, it is improved one. Will do things better.

Comment: but for the same way, i read it documentation but could not find how to use it the way i need

Comment: Your question is hard to follow... Are you trying to translate the cfhttp call above to some other approach? If so you need to post *that* code.  Just saying "it is not happening" does tell us much.  You need to include the actual code you have tried, the results (including any errors) and a description of how the result is different from what you expected.  [Ask]

Comment: @Leigh: Phewww, I do not know how to explain you, it is written in very simple english what i am trying to do. if you still need to know more what i am trying to do, read it carefully, Thanks

Comment: The title says you are "trying alternative" to cfhttp - presumably using the generic function in the link - somehow, but you did not include the *your* code. A link to a general function is fine, but you need to post your code demonstrating how you actually used it. How can anyone help you if they cannot even see your code or a dump of the result?

Comment: i think you did not checked, i posted the code, the title says i wanna try something else but the method i am trying is what i have shown above..., so my question is i am using the blog post which is cfhttp frustration, i had tried the same thing, i am saying it is not creating cookies, in the dump... so if you know java which i am sure u know, you can check that and guide why it is not working

Comment: No, you posted what you *were* using. You did NOT post your new code using the function in the blog post.  If you are having a problem with your code, you need to actually post it - not describe it! ["Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: don't eep me showing links how to ask, what to ask...  i gave link and tried the exact code he had, i am saying that his url way is not creating the cookies

Comment: *tried the exact code he had* Huh..? The code above does look not anything like it at all.

Comment: Which version of CF? (CF9 is broken w/some SSL certs.)  Did you modify the default CFHTTP USERAGENT parameter. (Default = "ColdFusion")  Some servers use filter rules or blacklists to block known abusive agents (ie, Bad Behavior WordPress plugin). You may want to also ensure you are using the port. http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/05/22/Important-note-about-ColdFusion-11-and-CFHTTP

Comment: @Leigh, you are so lazy that you cannot visit the blog, anyways leave it..

Comment: @James: I am using coldfusion10

Comment: @twistermetal - One of us is smoking something and it is not me ;-) You say you are trying to use something other than cfhttp, point to a blog that uses java, say you are using the exact same code (when it is completely different), then say you want to use cfhttp? WTH? I am going to chalk this up to a language barrier and move on. Good luck.

Comment: let me clarify this: I am saying here is: 1. I am using the cfhttp method and it is working fine. 2.) I pointed to the Blog post where I have used the same code and put my url to fetch the details, but it is not bringing the cookies in the cfdump. so all in all, there are two codes: 1 - cfhttp which i tried and working, 2) Code in Blog Post and tried [i never added that code in my original question, but i will add now], Blog post code never creates cookie, that is my question

Answer (score 1):

Ben Nadel ([www.bennadel.com](http://www.bennadel.com)) has created a great CFC for maintaining cookies and sessions between requests, that is hosted over at GitHub (https://github.com/bennadel/CFHTTPSession.cfc).

If you need to wait for the login to then request the data, I'm not sure threading it will work for you to speed it up. unless you just don't want the page to wait for any of it, then you can wrap the whole process in a thread.

the speed may be unavoidable if the server you are retrieving from is causing more of a delay then you'd like.